# Sinatra dropdown list

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

Im glad you answered my question about my dev issue, I'll try to be more self-explanatory this time.

I have a main app.rb where I use several endpoints redirecting to my Sinatra Haml views.My project is about a Software Portfolio, so I have this class: Software, and Category, which relationship is: one software has one category, and a category has many softwares. In the form where you create a new Software entry, I put a dropdown list where you can choose between 3 different categories: Desktop, Web and App. 
Until there, everything is going well. The thing is, when the Software list shows up, I want to put a dropdown list to filter by created categories (I already have the "add category" form with its Class) and I can't figure out how to add the filter within a Filter button in the software list form. Can you guys help me please? Of course I know how to put the button there, but I want to show only the software entries where the selected category matches. Here's the list form.

```
%select{:name => "category"}
 %option Desktop
 %option Web
 %option Device
 %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Filter", :class => "btn"}
%ul.list
 - @sware.each do |software|
  %div{:class =>"list-group"}
  %a{:href =>"/software/edit/#{software.id}", :class =>"btn btn-lg btn-primary"} 
   = software.title
   %a.pull-right(href="/software/delete/#{software.id}" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger")  Delete
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the point that @max pleaner made, you're not actually calling the right object in `params`. It should be  `params[:category]` and you should be able to rewrite that much simpler:

```
get '/all' do
    halt(401,'Not Authorized, please login to continue') unless session[:admin]
    @sware = Software.all
    haml :sware
end

post '/:category' do
    @sware = Software.title.where(categorization: {Software.categorization => params[:category]}
    haml :index # assuming index.haml is where you want to go
end
```

Then, assuming your file is properly indented, your Haml file should work as well:

```
%select{:name => 'category'}
    %option Desktop
    %option Web
    %option Device
%input{:type => 'submit', :value => 'Filter', :class => 'btn'}
%ul.list
    - @sware.each do |software|
        %div{:class =>'list-group'}
            %a{:href =>"/software/edit/#{software.id}", :class =>'btn btn-lg btn-primary'} 
                = software.title
            %a.pull-right{:href=>"/software/delete/#{software.id}" :class=>'btn btn-lg btn-danger'} Delete
```

Of course, the more information you can provide, the better the problem can be understood.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `index` method like this:

```
post '/all' do
    index(:category)
end
```

You're passing an argument to the `index` call, but the `index` method doesn't take any arguments.

Please include the full error with your question.

Comment: Adding to this answer, if you intend to execute the steps under a route `A` inside another route `B`, the right way to do it is to [redirect to that page](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Browser%20Redirect).

Answer (score 1):

`index` action can be DRY'ed:

```
def index
  category = case
             when params[:Web] then :Web
             when params[:Desktop] then :Desktop
             when params[:Device] then :Device
             end

  @sware = Software.title.where(categorization: { Software.categorization => category })
end
```

"It just doesn't work" is not a good place to start investigation of the problem. More debug information is required.